# Stackdriver Monitoring alerting: can I use functions instead of constants for Condition Threshold?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I am playing around with Stackdriver Monitoring alerting and having used Prometheus/Alertmanager a bit I am quite disappointed with the seeming lack of options.

For instance, I have a resource that emits one datapoint per day, an Epoch Second of the age of a certain resource. I would like to create an alert that compares the datapoint with the current time and if the resource is too old an alert should fire.

In Prometheus it would be expressed like this:

```
- alert: TooOldAlert
  expr: sum(time() - datapoint_epoch_second) BY (datapoint_group) > 48 * 60 * 60
  for: 1m
  labels:
    severity: critical
```

So if the age of the datapoint is more than 48 hours ago, I will be alerted.

There just doesn't seem to exist such an option in Stackdriver Monitoring alerting. I tried to check the API / programmatic interface as well but I came up short there as well.

TL;DR: Do built-in functions exist at all in Stackdriver Monitoring alerting?

Comment: Please provide more information about your use case and reason to switch from Prometheus/Alertmanager to Stackdriver Monitoring alerting.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I am moving some code from permanent service to cloud functions, since there is only ever data to process once every 24 hours there is no need to waste a complete service running 24 hours a day. The change will also alleviate my need of Prometheus. Stackdriver seemed like a good fit, but it is too optimized for 24/7-services and not enough for serverless/cloud functions.

Comment: if you only need one value per day, maybe you only need to setup the alignment/interpolation to sample less often. Take a look at `Aligner` api:  https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rpc/google.monitoring.v3#google.monitoring.v3.Aggregation.Aligner

Comment: @c69 that is a good first step, but still doesn't solve the problem that there is no time() function. Also the way Stackdriver handles absent values makes it hard to know when a value is truly missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackdriver Alerting *does* have built-in functions.  But they have to do with aggregating, filtering, comparing, and creating ratios.  See docs for alerting policies [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#Condition).  An example for setting them up is [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/policies-in-json#json-ratio).

However, there is no `time()` function that you can use to get epoch time in these expressions.  This is the rub.

In order to port your age alert into Stackdriver, one approach is to change the log "up-stream", so that your service emits a log for how old it is relative to "now". In this case, you can filter on the age without needing to invoke what time it is now.

If you cannot change the log structure in your service, you could choose to capture the log "down-stream" and do a transformation on it.  One approach is to sink this Stackdriver log to Pub/Sub, and have that event trigger a Cloud Function.  An example guide is [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/logging).

Comment: Thanks, but none of that is an option for me. The source of truth emits a data point exactly once every 24 hours so a time() function would be the only reliable way of monitoring it.